# PHPMailer With Shared Hosting (SMTP Transport)

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, shared-hosting

I have looked and looked for an answer to this and cannot find anything so If this already has an answer please let me know.

I am using PHPMailer and using SMTP to send emails with files attached.

Here is my Code:

```
                            <?php

                                /**
                                 * SMTP Server Using Yahoo To Upload Files And Submit, Port 465 Using SSL
                                 */
                                 require_once('PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
                                define('GUSER', '****@yahoo.com'); // Yahoo username
                                define('GPWD', '*****'); // Yahoo password

                                $msg = '';

                                if (array_key_exists('userfile', $_FILES)) {
                                    // First handle the upload
                                    // Don't trust provided filename - same goes for MIME types
                                    // See http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php#114004 for more thorough upload validation
                                    $uploadfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), sha1($_FILES['userfile']['name']));
                                    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
                                        // Upload handled successfully
                                        // Now create a message
                                        // This should be somewhere in your include_path
                                    $mail = new PHPMailer();  // create a new object
                                    $mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
                                    $mail->SMTPDebug = 4;  // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
                                    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;  // authentication enabled
                                    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
                                    $mail->Host = 'smtp.mail.yahoo.com';
                                    $mail->Port = 465;
                                    $mail->Username = GUSER;  
                                    $mail->Password = GPWD;           
                                    $mail->setFrom('****@yahoo.com', 'Sent File');
                                    $mail->addAddress('****@****.com');
                                    $mail->Subject = 'Test File';
                                    $mail->msgHTML("My message body");
                                    // Attach the uploaded file
                                    $mail->addAttachment($uploadfile, $_FILES['userfile']['name']);
                                    if (!$mail->send()) {
                                        $msg = "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
                                            } else {
                                                    $msg = "Message sent!";
                                                    }
                                    } else {
                                            $msg = 'Failed to move file to ' . $uploadfile;
                                            }
                                    }

                            ?>

                                <?php if (empty($msg)) { ?>
                                    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000"> Send this file: <input name="userfile" type="file">
                                        <input type="submit" value="Send File">
                                    </form>
                                <?php } else {
                                    echo $msg;
                                } ?>
```

When I Use This on my local lamp server it works perfectly, However when I use it on my Yahoo Hosting Server, I get this error: SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Permission denied (13)

Looking into what that error represents, It sounds like the problem and solution has to do with the 
httpd_can_sendmail
&
httpd_can_network_connect
Settings. It looks like they need to be activated. Source: http://gistpages.com/2013/09/14/phpmailer_smtp_error_failed_to_connect_to_server_permission_denied_13_fix

My problem is that with Yahoo, I cannot access a terminal to change these settings. Does anyone know of any other way to change these settings without having access to a linux terminal of the hosting server?

Thanks 
P.S I would not recommend using yahoo as a website hosting provider EVER to anyone!

Comment: yahoo is a poor choose, why not use your hosts mail server? or at least gamil

Comment: This is for a client's website who already uses yahoo as their website host and they have their emails and all that set up through yahoo mail. This mail function using SMTP can use any mail host, for example before I had it using googles mail server using tls instead of ssl. I changed it to yahoo since it is on a yahoo hosted server thinking it might help since it would be going through their mail servers at that point. But I still get an error(13) which means its a server permission setting, not a code syntax error.

Comment: yahoo host - ok :-) reads like you need to ask yahoo, they may block the port or otherwise set up their hosting not to support this.

Comment: You might be able to work around this if PHP is run via fastcgi, e.g. using PHP-FPM, as a user other than the web server user. That way PHP code has no direct connection with httpd and thus may not match the selinux restriction. Of course it may match something else, but it might not!